# Update table with joining another table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to set field `f1` in table `t1` with the value `122` if field `f2` in table `t2` has value `134`. Suppose field `f34` is the key between table `t1` and `t2`.
How would I write the query for this in SQL Developer?

Comment: Would be better for your career if you try your self before posting the answer here.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one (for Oracle):

```
UPDATE ( SELECT t1.f1, t2.f2
           FROM t1 
           JOIN t2
             ON t1.f34 = t2.f34
          WHERE t2.f2 = 134
       )
SET f1 = 122;
```

### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/87f7b/1)

For other RDBMS, try update with join

For SQL Server:

```
UPDATE t1 
SET    f1 = 122
FROM   t1 
       JOIN t2  
         ON t1.f34 = t2.f34
WHERE  t2.f2 = 134
```

### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7ef9/2)

For MySQL

```
UPDATE t1 temp1
  JOIN t2 temp2
    ON temp1.f34 = temp2.f34
SET    temp1.F1 = 122
WHERE  temp2.f2 = 134;
```

### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a426a7/1)

Comment: `sql-developer` tag is related to `Oracle`

Comment: @Grisha : nope, misconception, It can be used for MySql, Access, SQL-Server too.

Comment: @hims056 - `for normal SQL` it is funny :)

Answer (score 1):

```
update t1
set f1 = 122
where exists (select 1 from t2 where f34 = t1.f34 and f2 = 134)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update t1 a,t2 b set a.f1='122' where a.f34=b.f34 and b.f2=134;
```